# How to see if a process is suspended in unix

Tags: bash, unix, process

I'm trying to resume all processes that are suspended ,but i have no idea how to check if a process is suspended. I tried  but it dose not indicate if the process is suspended or running.

Comment: `ps` will show state = `T` for stopped processes.

Comment: "I tried but it does not indicate if the process is suspended". There's a word missing there, what did you try?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

You might use Ipor's way (`/proc/<pid>/status`) if you are using Linux but a more portable solution that should work with most Unix/Unix likes OSes would be to use a standard command as Barmar already suggested in a comment:

```
ps -o s= -p <pid>
```

This will show `T` for a suspended process (also if stopped because being debugged).

Comment: Great answer! For Mac OS X, you need to use `state=`.

Answer (score 2):

Examining process with pid `$pid` is easy:

```
if grep -q "^State.*stopped" /proc/$pid/status; then
    echo Process $pid is sleeping
else
    echo Process $pid is active
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -s
```

STAT column, tells you the status of the corresponding process(e.g T means the process has stopped)

or

```
ps -o stat
```

if you are aware of where things lie

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).