# How to run a second command which depend on the finish of the first command when the first command will suspend

Tags: bash, shell, process, jobs

I have a situation, image I have a first command to run which starts a db server, in the end of this command, it will suspend and listening on some port.  And I have the second command which is to start some web server to connect to the database from the first command.

Now I don't know how to write this simple command, tried:

```
A ; B
```

which doesn't work, because when A goes into suspend, b doesn't execute, if I type ctrl+c, then B starts, but it doesn't make sense anymore, because A is already terminated, so there's no database process.

I tried:

```
A && B
```

It doesn't work neither, B doesn't execute because A doesn't exit successful.

I thought of using:

```
A & B
```

which doesn't work sometimes, because when A is put into background, B immediately starts, so sometimes, B trying to connect to a database port when A hasn't finished, so there's no database process yet.

How can I achieve that B only starts when A successfully starts database?

Comment: Put some reasonable delay e.g. `A & sleep 20; B`

Comment: @anubhava, is it the only solution? delay cannot be exact, it will still fails sometimes.

Comment: A robust solution would be to run script `A` in background. Keep polling your *database* status using a script and only when database server is running, fire script `B`

Comment: @AaronShen You can either try to calculate an average time and go above so that it works or modify the way in which you're running command A or B. I mean, if command A doesn't end, then maybe start it in the background and sleep until you can retrieve an OK status to proceed with command B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little broad, but I guess it gets the point across

```
A&
while [ some_test_fails ]; do
    sleep some_time
done
B
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
A ; B
```

but B needs to ask A if it is fully started up. If yes go on with the actual execution of B. If not sleep some time and ask again. A poor mans solution for this asking might be the existence of a certain file.

I would not use the solution of anubhava, because it might lead to instabilities if the sleep time was too short.

Answer (score 0):

```
I thought of using:

A & B
```

Do than, and on process B you put a loop to check if A is suspended or not.

[How to see if a process is suspended in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037632/how-to-see-if-a-process-is-suspended-in-unix)

If A is suspended than B "Main" starts.